# Jade & JSON - Conditionals with boolean

Tags: json, pug

I created a presentation with Reveal.js, and I use Jade for templating, and JSON for translation (EN and FR). **I wish display an element of the list, with a boolean**, but the "false" element display everytime.

My Jade template

```
ul
    if "#{$i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.show}"
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-twitter
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.handle}

    if "#{$i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.show}"
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-facebook
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.handle}

    if "#{$i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.show}"
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-linkedin
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.handle}

    if "#{$i18n.global.outro.social.github.show}"
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.github.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-github
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.github.handle}
```

And my JSON

```
"social": {
    "twitter": {
        "url": "http://twitter.com",
        "handle": "MyTwitterName",
        "show": false
    },
    "facebook": {
        "url": "http://facebook.com",
        "handle": "Facebook Name",
        "show": true
    },
    "linkedin": {
        "url": "http://linkedin.com",
        "handle": "LinkedIn Name",
        "show": false
    },
    "github": {
        "url": "http://github.com",
        "handle": "Github Name",
        "show": true
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I found! Delete `#{}`.

```
ul
    if $i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.display
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-twitter
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.twitter.handle}

    if $i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.display
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-facebook
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.facebook.handle}

    if $i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.display
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-linkedin
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.linkedin.handle}

    if $i18n.global.outro.social.github.display
        li
            a(href='#{$i18n.global.outro.social.github.url}', target='_blank')
                i.fa.fa-github
                | #{$i18n.global.outro.social.github.handle}
```